# How to start HTTP Server from a Silverlight browser application. Alternative to HTTP Listener

Tags: silverlight, activex, httplistener, system.net

I need to start a lightweight HTTP Server from an ActiveX control that is running in a  Silverlight browser application. The HTTP Server runs in localhost.
My HTTP Server uses HTTPListener. 
I tested starting the HTTP Server from a test browser application that loads the same ActiveX control. It worked fine. When I  try to start the HTTP Server from the same ActiveX control that is on my Silverlight browser application I get the error at the following code:
    httpListener = new HttpListener()
The error is: **Operation is not supported on this platform**.

Is there an altertive way to implement HTTP Server that can be started from Silverlight browser?

Comment: Why do you need to start the HTTP server from an ActiveX control? This sounds like a fairly ugly solution. Can you start the server with an HTTP request? If so you can probably just make a call to localhost with WebClient from your Silverlight app.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Silverlight has many restrictions on sockets.